# ASP.NET MVC tries to use ControllerFactory to load resources?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've created a controller factory to be able to use Unity to resolve controller dependencies.
I get the following error:

> The IControllerFactory
>   'My.Name.Space.MyControllerFactory'
>   did not return a controller for the
>   name 'favicon.ico'.

Why does it try to use the controller factory to load resources and why doesn't it return 404 when the resource is not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return null;

        [...]
    }
}
```

Tells the factory to use the default handling.

Answer (score 4):

You could add the following to your routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
```